# Does bark on one edge of a wall stud pose a structural risk?

Tags: framing

During some recent renovations I discovered this gnarly stud within one of the walls of my basement.

Previously it was buried deep in a crawlspace and far away from any exposure to my family, but I've now opened a new entry to the crawlspace immediately next to this stud. The crawlspace will now be used for storage and this stud will be right next to anybody's face who accesses the crawlspace.

I recognize that it's just an old sap vein, but does it pose any danger if I leave it as-is? Thanks.

[image: stud with exposed sap vien]

Comment: Is that moss on there? I'm skeptical about moss coming out of the kiln drying process green. I'm skeptical of it remaining green in a crawlspace without significant moisture. Hygrometer's are as cheap as dirt from Amazon. I'd be tempted to toss one in there to verify that the relative humidity is below 85% most of the time.

Comment: It's not moss. It's a "fifth side", a region of bark from the board shape emerging from the log. And it's not green. You're seeing reflection from the sap sheen, mostly.

Comment: I revised your title to ask something more specific. If I'm off the mark, please revise further. Note that "dangerous" is subjective. See the [help] for types of questions to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not *dangerous.*

It's a crappy stud, but in a non bearing wall, who cares? Not the guy who put it in, and neither should you. If your kids play baseball, or violin, or do gymnastics, they get exposed to more rosin (dried softwood tree sap) than anyone's ever gonna get from that stud without chewing on it.

Comment: I agree, but it wouldn't even be dangerous in a bearing wall. No single common stud carries enough load that say 30% undersize is a problem.